# can erc20 token transaction work on Fast Sync-ed node ? OR it need Full node to transact any token?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, cpp-ethereum, fast-sync

I need help regarding couple doubts.

Which sync method is good for me. My client is asking me to make an Exchange website. Also ERC20 tokens will get transacted in this exchange.

Do I need a full node? Or Fast sync is Okay for ERC 20 tokens. I don't know exactly.

For this questions I need to know WHAT a Fast Sync node CAN NOT do what a Full node can do?

Also which one I should sync? GO/Geth or CPP node ?
Do they vary in performance or any other parameter ?

Any new suggestions are welcome guys.